# how do i load dictionary from text file?

Tags: python, list, dictionary

very new to python and programming in general.
I'm trying to make a program which is able to save ingredients with nutritional values as dictionaries in a txt file and then, if needed, pull it.
i got down the saving part quite well but I'm having problem with the load.
here's the code:

```
dict = []
def load():
    test = open("C:/Users/97254/Documents/תכנות/dietplanner/data/dictionary.txt","r")
    for line in test:
        if line != '\n':
            dict.append(line)
load()
#dict 2 is identical to dict[0] and i made it in order to check if the problem is in my understading of dictionaries or the code itself
dict2 = {'name': 'egg', 'gram': 12.0, 'carbs': 2.0, 'protein': 3.0, 'fats': 1.0, 'calories': 4.0}
print(dict2)
print(dict2['name'])
ingredient = dict[0]
print(ingredient)
print(ingredient['name'])
```

here's the output:

```
{'name': 'egg', 'gram': 12.0, 'carbs': 2.0, 'protein': 3.0, 'fats': 1.0, 'calories': 4.0}
egg
{'name': 'egg', 'gram': 12.0, 'carbs': 2.0, 'protein': 3.0, 'fats': 1.0, 'calories': 4.0}

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\97254\Documents\תכנות\dietplanner\venv\test.py", line 13, in <module>
    print(ingredient['name'])
TypeError: string indices must be integers
```

here's the txt file:

```
{'name': 'egg', 'gram': 12.0, 'carbs': 2.0, 'protein': 3.0, 'fats': 1.0, 'calories': 4.0}
{'name': 'ham', 'gram': 1.0, 'carbs': 2.0, 'protein': 3.0, 'fats': 4.0, 'calories': 2.0}
```

can someone help?

Comment: `dict = []` hmm `dict` is a really misleading name for a `list`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ingredient` in your code, is string type not dict, you can use `eval(str)` transform it to dict.
For example:

```py
ingredient = '''{'name': 'egg', 'gram': 12.0, 'carbs': 2.0, 'protein': 3.0, 'fats': 1.0, 'calories': 4.0}'''

ingredient = eval(ingredient)
print(ingredient['name'])
```

egg

Comment: @YonatanShofty you **really** shouldn't be doing this. Don't just dump the string representation of a dict to a text file. Use an existing serialization format, like JSON